# Keras Model for Molecular Activity

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I am experimenting with the Merku molecular activity challenge and I have created the train and test dataset.

The shape of the data is the following:

```
x_train.shape=(1452, 4306)
y_train.shape=(1452, 1) 
x_test.shape=(363, 4306)
y_test.shape=(363, 1)
```

I have used the `Dense` layer for defining the model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu",  input_shape=(4306,)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(25, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer="adam",
)
model.summary()
# Train the model
model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=300,
    epochs=900,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    shuffle=True
)
```

While trying the above code, the following error occurred:

`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_23: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2`

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Like this-model.add(Dense(100, activation = "relu",  input_shape=(4306,), batch_size=300, input_size=6252312))

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the flatten layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu",  input_shape=(4306,)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(25, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

The data sent to sequential layers is essentially 1-D (ignoring the batch column) so there's nothing to flatten. The data entering the flatten layer is already 1D.

EDIT -- for regression:

Categorical crossentropy is not an appropriate cost function for regression, you need to use mean-square error, which is commonly used for all regression tasks:

```
model.compile(
    loss='mse',
    optimizer="adam",
)
```

Comment: Thank you,Sir-the y is a numpy array and it has full of float numbers. to_categorical() is used for the converting class to number for classificatioin but it is regression method. Can you help me..

Comment: If its float numbers, is your goal regression? Or are you trying to classify to discrete classes?

Comment: Yes, sir it is regression- From weights of molecules, The molecular activity is to be predicted

Comment: Actually, It is the Merku Molecular Activity Challenge

Comment: Ok then, no need to encode y-vector. I though you were doing classification, since you are using 'categorical-crossentropy as loss function. Will edit post for regression

Comment: Sir, It is working, Thank you. Could you please suggest me other model for this molecular activity problem because using sequential is very basic..it has more than 1000 columns which modle can I used to do the experiment

Comment: There are a lot of options really, and it depends a lot on your data. But limiting it just to ANN's, if your data has more than 1000 columns (features), you can increase the number of nodes in your current models hidden layers substantially (up to 1000 and more). You can add more hidden layers etc. This depends a lot on your data. So play around with the network parameters a bit and see what works! P.S. If this solved your problem, please mark the question as accepted so it is resoved